# Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net

How do I fix a runtime exception preventing file or assembly from loading properly to successfully execute the following code?

I am trying to run the following code without success:

```
dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);
```

**Mail Exception**

> Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79219bf4e5ecaaca' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Packages.config**

```
 <package id="SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Clearly I have the file and reference installed from NuGet.

**How do I resolve this assembly reference exception?**

Comment: What version of .NET are you compiling your program in?

Comment: I see project Target Framework  = 4.5.2

Comment: In my experience the packages.config can lie. Can you find the dll in the bin folder? Sometimes you have to manually remove the line from packages.config, remove the reference and add it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution.  I deleted the dll, remove the packages.config line, then re installed the dependency in NuGet but the error remains.

Comment: I would suggest to remove targetframework attribute from package tag and try restoring packages.

Comment: After uninstalling Sendgrid, then the mentioned package, and re-installing both, I still cannot get past the error